# Call Rails API in Oracle BPEL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, bpel

I'm trying to integrate a simple Rails app with a BPEL process but it's been hard since BPEL has few or maybe none support for RESTfull web services.

I've tried already using a HTTP binding but i'm not sure if I got what I want since the component moved to the internal side, and it's actually an external service.

So I have two questions:

1. I needed to write the xsd file to define the request and response xml structure. I searched and it seems there is no gem for doing this automatically. Is there any? Or even better, is there a gem that creates something like a wsdl file? I know this is for SOAP web services and  in RESTful there is no such thing, but creating this files by hand is a pain in the ass. So I search something similar.
2. HTTP binding is the only way I found to call a RESTfull web service. Is there anything better? Has anyone been successful using it? Or code it in Java and use the Java adapter or something would be easier?

Any suggestion, even if not directly for my questions are appreciated. Thanks.

Also if there are some articles about it, links are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WashOut](http://roundlake.github.com/wash_out/) is a new SOAP server library and definitely worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks! Seems a great gem to create and publish non-REST web services. I don't know why I haven't found it before.